# Swift 4 Array get reference

Tags: arrays, swift, class, var

I ran into an issue with arrays in Swift. The problem is that it's a value type in Swift. I'm trying to find a workaround. 
Here is the code that I have:

```
class Object: Codable{
    var name : String?
}

var objects: Array<Object>?
objects = Array<Object>()
if var obj = objects { // <----- Creates a copy of array here
    let o = Object()
    o.name = "1"
    objects?.append(o)
    print(obj) //<----- this one is missing "o" object
    print(objects)
}
```

I cannot use `NSMutableArray` because I have an array inside another codable class.

What's everybody's experience on this one? If somebody can share a solutions for that.

Comment: Array is a structure not a class. You can't pass it as reference

Comment: You have to wrap it in a class if you want reference semantics.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying it's a value type. I was wondering if there are solutions to that already. Similar as it'd be done in ObjC

Answer (score 0):

Getting used to arrays as value types isn't too tough really. If i were you my version of the code would just look like this

```
var objects: Array<Object>?
objects = Array<Object>()
if var unwrappedObjs = objects {
    let o = Object()
    o.name = "1"
    unwrappedObjs.append(o)
    objects = unwrappedObjs
}
```

or alternatively maybe this:

```
var objects: Array<Object>?
objects = Array<Object>()
if objects != nil {
    let o = Object()
    o.name = "1"
    objects?.append(o)
}
```

Lastly you could always try making your own "ReferenceArray" class that wraps the array APIs and gives you reference semantics but that seems like overkill. Sooner rather than later, arrays as value types will seem natural to reason about.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that was exactly my thoughts to solve it:) but I was thinking if I am overlooking something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

bitwit already mentioned this to a point, but I think that your biggest mistake is simply not accepting the new object as the source. Unless it's important to retain the `Array<Object>?` you should replace it with the `Array<Object>` one.

```
var objects: Array<Object>?
objects = Array<Object>()

if var objects = objects { // <----- Creates a copy of array here
    let o = Object()
    o.name = "1"
    objects.append(o) // objects is now the non-optional one
    print(objects)
}
```

If it needs to be in the same scope, use `guard`:

```
var objects: Array<Object>?
objects = Array<Object>()

guard var objects = objects else { // <----- Creates a copy of array here
    fatalError()
}

let o = Object()
o.name = "1"
objects.append(o) // objects is now the non-optional one
print(objects)
```

If you absolutely need an array to be referenced, you can make a container class:

```
public class ReferenceContainer<Element> {
    public var element: Element

    init(_ element: Element) {
        self.element = element
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Array<Object>? is just for example, In general I was thinking if there is more elegant way to deal with that.

Comment: Yeah, there are definitely circumstances where reference semantics for arrays are preferred, but in many of those using a wrapper object can help in the long run, organizationally.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the main confusion is that logically when unwrapping object I would assume to get the same object but not copy of it.